# How to import .sql file in postgresql 12.2

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore, postgresql-12

I am using PostgreSQL 12.2, and I have some *.sql files to import into a database

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d iotmaster -f D:\iotmaster.sql
```

But I am facing this Error

```
pg_restore: error: options -d/--dbname and -f/--file cannot be used together
```

How to import .sql file in my database?

Comment: A SQL script is applied using `psql`, e.g. `psql -U your_user -d your_db -f iotmaster.sql`

Comment: I try that but it shows `The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database.`

Comment: Well, [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) the input file for `pg_restore` is **not** specified with `-f`, so you need to use `pg_restore -U postgres -d iotmaster iotmaster.sql`  (but choosing `.sql` as the extension for a custom dump was a really bad idea)

Comment: thanks it's work for me